# Rails - create seeds.rb for has_many with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create seeds.rb for specific vitrage gem. I have working prototype for simple title element:

```
app/models/vitrage_pieces/vtrg_title.rb: 

module VitragePieces
  class VtrgTitle < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :slot, class_name: "VitrageOwnersPiecesSlot", as: :piece

    def params_for_permit
      [:number, :title]
    end

  end
end
```

And title elements easily created with:

```
db/seeds.rb:

subjects[0].vitrage_slots.create ordn: 1, piece: VitragePieces::VtrgTitle.create(title: "Simple title", number: 1)
```

But how can I create seeds for this kind of gallery? Each gallery has type of skin (gallery or slider), can have many gallery images, and each image has its own title and url.

```
app/models/vitrage_pieces/vtrg_gallery.rb: 

module VitragePieces
  class VtrgGallery < ActiveRecord::Base

    AS_GALLERY = 0
    AS_SLIDER = 1

    has_one :slot, class_name: "VitrageOwnersPiecesSlot", as: :piece
    has_many :gallery_images, dependent: :delete_all

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_images, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

    validates_associated :gallery_images

    def params_for_permit
      [:gal_type, :gallery_images, gallery_images_attributes: [:id, :title, :image, :image_cache, :_destroy]]
    end

  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1 and Ruby 2.2.3.

Comment: Are you using paperclip for image uploading ?

Comment: @Aschen nope, carriervawe with mini magick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a nested hash because of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` :

```
gallery_image_attribute = {
  gal_type: AS_SLIDER,
  gallery_images_attributes: [
    {
      title: "Foo",
      image: Rails.root.join("foo.png").open
    },
    {
      title: "Bar",
      image: Rails.root.join("bar.png").open
    }
  ]
}
VitragePieces::VtrgGallery.create(gallery_image_attribute)
```

[Carrierwave doc](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file)

Comment: great, thank you! one small addition: it didn't work out with gal_type: AS_SLIDER, but works excellent with gal_type: 1

Comment: You should use an enum for `gal_type`, it's work perfectly for field with a fixed value like this. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html